# Best way to find object in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, find, nsarray

I have array with arrays ex.:
(
 (
  object,
  object
 ),
 (
  object,
  object,
  object,
  object
 )
)

Each `object`has property `.objectID`.What is the best way to find object with specific `objectID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options for you:

Option 1: using nested for loops

```
CustomObject *searchingObject;

// searching through the first array (which has arrays inside of it)
// Note: this will stop looping if it searched through all the objects or if it found the object it was looking for
for (int i = 0; i < [firstArray count] && searchingObject; i++) {

    // accessing the custom objects inside the nested arrays
    for (CustomObject *co in firstArray[i]) {

        if ([co.objectId == 9235) {
            // you found your object
            searchingObject = co; // or do whatever you wanted to do.
            // kill the inside for-loop the outside one will be killed when it evaluates your 'searchingObject'
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: using blocks:

```
// you need __block to write to this object inside the block
__block CustomObject *searchingObject;

// enumerating through the first array (containing arrays)
[firstArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *nestedArray, NSUInteger indx, BOOL *firstStop) {

    // enumerating through the nested array
    [nestedArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomObject *co, NSUInteger nestedIndx, BOOL *secondStop) {

        if ([co.objectId == 28935) {
            searchingObject = co; // or do whatever you wanted to do.
            // you found your object now kill both the blocks
            *firstStop = *secondStop = YES;
        }
    }];
}];
```

Although still considered N^2 execution time these will only run as far as they need to. Once they find the object they cease searching.

Answer (score 2):

try it with

```
[ary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectID == %@", objectID]];
```

--

```
id object = nil;
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectID == %@", objectID];    

for(NSArray *subAry in ary)
{
    NSArray *result = [subAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    if(result && result.count > 0)
    {
        object = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        break;
    }
}
```

for Zombies cares everyone himself :P

Comment: If you set the predicate appropriately, yes.

Comment: @Wain I know, thing is he did not in this answer, hence it does not apply to the question.

Comment: yes, sorry ^^ wanted to lookup the predicate for array in array in my code :D this only works if you have already access to the object in the hirarchy

Comment: hmm, can't find a working `predicate` for **Arrays in Arrays** :/ have only predicates for sets of objects (for coreData). But a usual `array` has no fitting attributes I could ask for with `SUBQUERY` or `ANY` or `self in` i.e. I would iterate every subarray an filter with this predicate

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned with order, you could instead use an array of dictionaries where the objectId is the key.  That makes your search O(N).